# How to find the URL of the API calls in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm a user of a Windows application that does some work for me online.

It calls to a certain website to get and post data.

I don't know the URL of this website but I want to find out.

I have the application installed but I don't have its source code.

How can I find out this API URL? Any specific decompiler or software I can use to achieve it?

Comment: Bro, i suggest you to use fiddler, its a mitm proxy which can interpret http request check it [here](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you could even edit response , request made from api using fiddler

Comment: Do you know that it's a C# application? If not, please can you remove the tag?

Comment: @Agent_Orange Thanks a lot! Post it as an answer so I can select your answer as correct.

Comment: @john It is a C# application

Comment: Then you can try JetBrains' DotPeek, or Redgate's Reflector to peruse the reverse-compiled code (which may not be particularly user-friendly if the application's code has been obfuscated). Fiddler would be the better option if the application supports proxies/auto-detects proxies.